# How to estimate the value of function using some information about it and its derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a real valued differentiable function such that

> $f(x)+f'(x)\leq 1, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=0.$

What would be the maximum possible value for $f(1)?$

I used MVT and the only things that I got is that $f(1)=f'(c)$, for some $c\in (0,1)$.

Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $g(x)=e^xf(x)$, and then $g'(x)\le e^x$, which implies
$$g(1)-g(0)=\int_0^1 g'(x) dx \le \int_0^1 e^x dx = e-1 $$
i.e.
$$f(1)\le\frac{e-1}{e}$$
and the equality holds when $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the function $g(x)=e^x f(x)$, then $g'(x)=(f(x)+f'(x))e^x\leq e^x$.

Consequently $g(1)-g(0) \leq e-1$ which gives $f(1) \leq 1-1/e$.

This value is reached if $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ which is the solution of the ODE $y'+y=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can argue that you always want $f'(x)$ to be as large as possible and solve the differential equation
$$f'(x)+f(x)=1\\f(0)=0\\f(x)=-e^{-x}+1\\f(1)=1-e^{-1}$$

Comment: why f′(x)  to be as large as possible? I thought it has to be small !

Comment: You want it large because that makes $f(x)$ grow.  Another function that meets the requirement is $f(x)=0$, which has $f'(x)=0$ so it doesn't grow.

Comment: The solution of $y'+y=1$ is $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ and not the one you gave